# Jmeter - How to use dynamically extracted value from a request in a JSR223 PreProccesor

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am simply extracting a session ID and a User ID from a request.   I am looking to concatenate them using groovy like:

```
vars.put("conjoined", vars.get("sessionId" + vars.get("UserId")))
log.info("runnerId value is==========================" +  vars.get("conjoined"))
```

Because they are extracted values and not variables they are null.  What library can I use to get those values within the JSR223?

Answer (score 0):

1. [PreProcessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors/) are being executed **before** the request so the variables have not been extracted at this point
2. There is a syntax error in your first line, it should look like:

   ```
   vars.put('conjoined', vars.get('sessionId') + vars.get('UserId'))
   ```

   check out [JMeterVariables JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) for more details
3. There is no need to "conjoin" the variables, you can just use normal [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) syntax, something like:

   ```
   ${sessionId}${UserId}
   ```